# How to change rownames by one position

Tags: r

I´m new with R. I would like to know how can I down or up one position in rows with rownames with dates. I can´t substract 1 because (Monday -1) is Sunday and it should be friday in the dataset given.

For example:

```
library(quantmod)
library(TTR)

start = as.Date("1990-01-01")
end = as.Date("2018-10-26")


getSymbols("^GSPC", src = "yahoo", from = start, to = end) #
na.omit(GSPC)

tail(GSPC)
```

With this, we get:

```
           GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close GSPC.Volume GSPC.Adjusted
2018-10-12   2770.54   2775.77  2729.44    2767.13  3966040000       2767.13
2018-10-15   2763.83   2775.99  2749.03    2750.79  3300140000       2750.79
2018-10-16   2767.05   2813.46  2766.91    2809.92  3428340000       2809.92
2018-10-17   2811.67   2816.94  2781.81    2809.21  3321710000       2809.21
2018-10-18   2802.00   2806.04  2755.18    2768.78  3616440000       2768.78
2018-10-19   2775.66   2797.77  2760.27    2767.78  3566490000       2767.78
2018-10-22   2773.94   2778.94  2749.22    2755.88  3307140000       2755.88
2018-10-23   2721.03   2753.59  2691.43    2740.69  4348580000       2740.69
2018-10-24   2737.87   2742.59  2651.89    2656.10  4709310000       2656.10
2018-10-25   2674.88   2722.70  2667.84    2704.61  2507243461       2704.61
```

And what I want is the same DF (or another) but with one position left. In this case, this:

```
           GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close GSPC.Volume GSPC.Adjusted
2018-10-11   2770.54   2775.77  2729.44    2767.13  3966040000       2767.13
2018-10-12   2763.83   2775.99  2749.03    2750.79  3300140000       2750.79
2018-10-15   2767.05   2813.46  2766.91    2809.92  3428340000       2809.92
2018-10-16   2811.67   2816.94  2781.81    2809.21  3321710000       2809.21
2018-10-17   2802.00   2806.04  2755.18    2768.78  3616440000       2768.78
2018-10-18   2775.66   2797.77  2760.27    2767.78  3566490000       2767.78
2018-10-19   2773.94   2778.94  2749.22    2755.88  3307140000       2755.88
2018-10-22   2721.03   2753.59  2691.43    2740.69  4348580000       2740.69
2018-10-23   2737.87   2742.59  2651.89    2656.10  4709310000       2656.10
2018-10-24   2674.88   2722.70  2667.84    2704.61  2507243461       2704.61
```

Answer (score 0):

The time column in this dataframe is not considered to be a separate column (i.r., a feature), however if you want you can add such column to it.
You can get this column by `t = GSPC[,0]`.

Comment: Have you tried your solution? `GSPC[, 0]` is a data frame with 0 columns. When you say that *"The time column in this dataframe is not considered to be a separate column"* you are clearly wrong, that is not a column at all, it is the `row.names`, an [attribute](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/attributes.html).

Answer (score 0):

The following could be made shorter, with less code lines, but I am writing it like this in order to make more clear.

```
rn <- row.names(GSPC)
rn <- as.Date(rn)
rn <- c(rn[1] - 1, rn[-length(rn)])
row.names(GSPC) <- rn
```